# Gem NameError when called from other gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to get [PartyFoul](https://github.com/dockyard/party_foul) set up on a Rails project I collaborate on and am running into a weird issue when I run the install generator.

```
~/.rvm/gems/.../party_foul-1.5.4/lib/generators/party_foul/install_generator.rb:21:in `rescue in create_initializer_file': uninitialized constant PartyFoul::InstallGenerator::Octokit (NameError)
from ~/.rvm/gems/.../gems/party_foul-1.5.4/lib/generators/party_foul/install_generator.rb:17:in `create_initializer_file'
```

The script is having trouble finding the [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) gem so if I put `require 'octokit'` at the top of `install_generator.rb`, everything is happy. The weird part is that I can't replicate this issue on a clean Rails 4 or Rails 3.2 project that simply has PartyFoul installed, so it must be specific to this project, and while I can get the configuration file set up manually, I'd like to figure out what root cause of this problem is.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, the PartyFoul gem was in the `:production` group so I'm assuming that Rails was somehow not loading it properly. I replicated the `NameError` in the clean Rails project after moving the gem to `:production`, so that seems to be the difference. I'm not sure what the root cause is, any enlightenment would still be appreciated :-).